# Select DDPages before exporting

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, data-driven-pages

I have script for exporting separate data driven pages (script tool in a toolbox).

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
pageNumbers = [4,7,11] #select pages before exporting
    for pageNum in pageNumbers: 
    mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum 
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, r"C:\Path" + str(pageNum) + ".jpg")
del mxd
```

Is it possible to change the page numbers in the brackets without changing the code manually?

I mean, after clicking the link, you will be brought to a window to choose the pages you would like to export. There may be checkboxes drawn next to the page numbers or text boxes with the page numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use script parameters to do this.  Right click on your script in the toolbox and open the properties window.  From here open the Parameters tab and add a new parameter with a value type of long, you can label it as you like.

In the Parameter Properties options below change the MultiValue option to 'Yes'.

If you run your script now you will get an input window to enter the required page numbers.

From there you can pull them into your page number list with:

```
pageNumbers = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
```

You can get more information about working with Parameters here

[Understanding Script Tool Parameters](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/understanding-script-tool-parameters.htm)

Comment: Thanks. It works. I use parameter GetParameter  `import arcpy
import os  
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")   

pageNumbers = arcpy.GetParameter(0) 
splitthreshold = pageNumbers
for pageNum in splitthreshold:  
    mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = int(pageNum)
 
    arcpy.AddMessage("Page {0} has been exported".format(pageNum))
      
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, r"C:\Temp\\" +str(pageNum) + ".jpg", resolution=200)   
del mxd  `

Comment: Because when i using the arcpy.GetParameterAsText() function and put number e.g. '25' then the value will be converted to a string with two numbers ('2' and '5') separated by a semicolon.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working.  One suggestion is to remove the splitthreshold object.  It is just a copy of the pageNumbers list.

`import arcpy 
import os mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") 

pageNumbers = arcpy.GetParameter(0) 

for pageNum in pageNumbers: 
 mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = int(pageNum) 
 arcpy.AddMessage("Page {0} has been exported".format(pageNum)) 
 arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, r"C:\Temp\\" +str(pageNum) + ".jpg", resolution=200) 
del mxd`